# Activity started from service visibility null

Tags: android

i am trying to have an activity launched from a service.

My problem is hiding/showing this activity.

The activity is started like so

```
        overlay = new BubbleOverlay();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, overlay.getClass()).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Activity:

```
public class BubbleOverlay extends Activity {

private boolean active = false;
private View mainView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.overlay_layout);
    mainView = findViewById(R.id.main_overlay_layout);
    if(mainView == null)
        Log.d("BubbleOverlay", "onCreate: MainView is null");
}

public void setActive(boolean value){
    active = value;
}

public void hide(){
    active = false;
    mainView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

public void show(){
    active = true;
    mainView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

I am trying to toggle the visibility of the mainView from the service.

```
        Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable_longClick = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            overlay.hide();
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable_longClick, 5000);
```

this produces the following error:

```
07-28 05:51:56.549 21690-21690/com.derp.derp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.derp.derp, PID: 21690
                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at com.derp.derp.BubbleOverlay.hide(BubbleOverlay.java:37)
                                                                      at com.derp.derp.BubbleService$4.run(BubbleService.java:181)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6044)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the `Null Pointer Exception` is the mainView has not been initialised before its use. This happens because the Activity's `onCreate()` method which holds the object's initialise statement has not been called (with respect to the overlay object you created inside your `Service`). The onCreate() method will only be called once the `Activity` is created.

In order to call the hide() method of the `Activity` from the `Service` you need to create a proper communication channel between the Activity and the Service i.e. you need to **bind the Service to your Activity**. I know, this approach requires a bit of coding efforts but its the best approach and it will guarantee you flawless and smooth functioning for your app.

Comment: Will this work for any activity? Or does it have to be bound to the activity that started the service?

Comment: Any activity can be bound to the Service. If you need the Service to run in the background without any Activity or continue running in the background while you switch between Activities then you need to start the Service first. Then you can bind the Service to any Activity you want.

Comment: This technique (the one I described in the above comment) is a combination of both techniques 1. Started Service and 2. Bound Service